# element fades in/out more than once on mouseover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a simple fade function on mouseover. The problem is that the element fades in and out more than once after the intended item is moused over and then out. I am including my jquery code below along with the accompanying HTML. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.claimfile-text').hide();
        $('.claimfile-graphic').mouseover(function(){
            $('.claimfile-text').fadeIn();
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $('.claimfile-text').fadeOut();
        });

    });
```

(Claim file)
(hover to reveal)

```
        <div class="claimfile-text fade-box case-text">
            <p>Claimant</p>
        </div><!-- end claimfile-text -->
```

Comment: Have you tried adding .stop() (http://api.jquery.com/stop/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use:

```
$(".claimfile-graphic").hover(function(){
  $(".claimfile-text").fadeIn();
}, function(){
  $(".claimfile-text").fadeOut();
});
```

Hover comprises of two event handlers - handlerIn and handlerOut.
More - http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Hey thanks man, this offers even less code, so I'm opting for it. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the rest of your html you'll be wanting [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
 $('.claimfile-text').stop().fadeIn();
```

This will:

> Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Comment: Thanks for the description, sure helps me understand it's function. Thanks.